# Reverse date from %d-%m-%y to %y-%m-%d in pandas dataframe with np.where

Tags: python, pandas, where-clause

I wan't to reverse the dates from a imported CSV file from %d-%m-%y to %y-%m-%d. I like to do something like this:

df['date'] = np.where((df['date'], '%d-%m-%y'), df['date'].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')), df['date'])

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv', parse_dates=['date'], dayfirst=True, dtype=str) \
  .to_csv('norm.csv', date_format='%Y-%m-%d', index=False)
```

Input `file.csv`:

```
date,value
30-03-2023,10
```

Output `norm.csv`:

```
date,value
2023-03-30,10
```